# Override a default mime-type when using the Sling MimeTypeService

Tags: mime-types, sling

I am using the [Sling MimeTypeService](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/commons/mime/MimeTypeService.html) in order to get an appropriate extension for a given file & trying to override a default extension with my own.

E.g. if I had a method:

```
@Reference
MimeTypeService mimeTypeService;

public void getPlainTextAsDiff() {
    mimeTypeService.registerMimeType("text/plain", ".diff");
    mimeTypeService.getExtension("text/plain"); //returns ".txt"        
}
```

This returns ".txt" rather than ".diff", ignoring the first line of the method.
This also seems to be inline with the documentation:

> A MIME type may be mapped to multiple extensions (e.g. text/plain to
> txt, log, ...). This method is expected to returned one of those
> extensions. **It is up to the implementation to select an appropriate
> extension if multiple mappings exist for a single MIME type.**
>
> *[My emphasis]*

I'm wondering if it's possible to circumvent this somehow, e.g. deregistering a mime-type or ranking those available, so that in the case above "diff" would guaranteed to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend mime type mappings by providing [MimeTypeProvider](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/commons/mime/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/commons/mime/MimeTypeProvider.java) services, but looking at the [MimeTypeServiceImpl](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/commons/mime/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/commons/mime/internal/MimeTypeServiceImpl.java) code it looks like those are not sorted by service ranking. If I'm correct, you won't have a way to prioritize you MimeTypeProviders. You might want to experiment with this and submit an enhancement request or patch.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand! I'll look into it further & hopefully provide a patch, if I come across a feasible solution.